# How to rotate objects clamped to a curve around the axis of the curve?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I have been playing with creating objects using array and curve modifiers.  Here's a simple play example of a partial dog collar created using a small rectangular piece of collar replicated along a curve:

[image]

The collar follows a roughly circular Bezier curve:

[image]

The problem I'm running into is that, as you can see, while the collar follows the curve, it is tilted like a cone, with the top diameter bigger than the bottom.  I *thought* the best way to fix this would be to move the handles of the control points of the curve to rotate along the axis, but I can't seem to do that -- the handles change tangents,and don't rotate the curve itself (which makes sense for a 2D object, I guess).

If I grab the collar and rotate it, it just moves off the curve.

Is there a way to manipulate this so that each individual unit of the array will rotate along the axis of the curve so that it will straighten up rather than leaning out?

Comment: You can change the tilt of the curve by Ctrl+T.

Comment: also make sure that the curve is Method > Z-Up

Comment: That's it!  It works great.  Thanks.   I'd accept this as an answer, but I don't know how to do it to a comment.